# Remote Procedure Call between Java and C

Tags: java, c, sockets, xml-rpc, rpc

I'm looking for a way to implement RPC between Java and C. What are the options to do this?

Best Wishes

p.s  I have web java application which is hosted on Glassfish server and C daemon. I need to directly call functions from bought sides.

Comment: Have you looked at JNI? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of RPC is to let two opaque processes on different systems talk to each other over a network. The languages used are irrelevant, except that you have to learn the corresponding RPC libraries for both languages.

Comment: I found a solution for RPC between Java and C - CORBA. Is this a solution and is this often used?

Comment: Yes, extensively in military application: JTRS-SCA (Joint Tactical Radio System-Software Communication Architecture) specification in military SDR (Software Defined Radio)-based radio

Answer (score 1):

Google [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html) address some of the difficulties with serialization, and provide a "RPC service" abstraction.  You'll need to implement the "remote" part -- sending the data across, etc. -- but it'll give you cross-language compatible serialization.

The Google implementation doesn't natively support C -- only C++ -- but it looks like C is one of the languages for which there is an [add-on](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the open source "thrift" library (originally from facebook). It also supports generating local stubs in a multiple of languages. Though I suspect the protocol buffer library as suggested by @Louis Wasserman  is higher quality than thrift.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of java libraries implementing oncrpc:

http://code.google.com/p/nio-jrpc/ and 
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/remotetea/wiki/WikiStart.